# How can check if there's a data in Oracle partition for a given day?

Tags: oracle11g

How can I "ping" multi-day Oracle partition and check if it contains data for a given day?

Ideally something that works fast.

Comment: `select ... where ..`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it will have to scan the whole partition. looking for something that uses dictionary tables

Comment: No it won't if you provide the correct `where` clause